# Works on Emulator and Safari browser but not on real IPhone

Tags: iphone, emulation

I am building a website that runs on IPhone. I am facing a issue where in the application works on browsers and emulator. But its not working on real IPhone device.(Basically my login submit is not happening on IPhone!)

Also the console doesnt shown me any error on IPhone. Have anybody faced such an issue. What could be the issue any idea.......solution is appreciated!

Thanks,
Justin Samuel.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  All we know is that login submit isn't working on the iPhone.  Is this javascript?  Is this php?  Does the website expect any of the many architectures available to a desktop but unavailable to the iPhone?

Comment: the ONLY possibility is your iPhone's too slow to run your javascript. iPhone Simulator uses same WebKit as iPhone uses, the only difference is that iPhone simulator's Webkit is build on i386 arch, instead of armv6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue.Basically my config has a setting which gives my site url. eg: currently it was something like http://xyz.com.

Now this worked on normal browsers and emulators. But when it comes to IPHone i had to change the config variable with something like http://**www**.xyz.com.

Browser was smart enuf to find out what the handle this but not IPhone browser.

Thanks Mahboudz and Mike for you valuble time. Yes I should have added more details while giving the question. Sorry for that!!

Thanks All.